# RubyMine + Vagrant: rake doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have manage to add remote SDK from my Vagrant machine and everything is working find except `rake`.

Everytime I run a `rake` task for example: `rake about`, it always return

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the `rake` command in detail

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -e '$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)' /htdocs/my-projects/my-app/bin/spring rake about
```

I have tried to "Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)" but it seems doesn't work.

Is there any configuration that I missed here?

Thanks.

Comment: There was an issue with rake tasks and remote Vagrant SDK (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17622) Could you please check the last EAP (2016.2)?

Comment: @Olivia Thanks. I will try the EAP and report my finding here later.

Comment: @Olivia I tried the 162.1024.4 and it works. My issue has been resolved. When the EAP going to be a public release?